# Pip install differences between local install and installing from Git

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have custom repository that looks similarly to following:

```
my_package
├── conf
|   └── cfg.yaml
├── sub_package
|   └── utils.py
└── some_module.py
README.md
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

When I use local install (`pip install .`) everything works fine but when I try to install my package from Git (`pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/to/repo/my_package.git`) I cannot find `conf` with `cfg.yml` in my installation location (I see only modules and `.py` files). **What causes such difference?**

This is content of my `setup.py` - [here](https://github.com/sxooler/conf-project/blob/main/setup.py). I'm using `include_package_data=True`, but no `MANIFEST.in`.

Since my repository is proprietary, I cannot share the repo, I was trying to reproduce this behavior and create MWE, but I was not able to do it (`setup.py` comes from [this demo project](https://github.com/sxooler/conf-project) and is same like the real one, but this demo project in both cases - installing locally or through Git - works completely same and conf subdir with not `.py` file is included).

I also try to compare `sdist` and `bdist` (running locally `python setup.py sdist` and `python setup.py bdist`) but both source and binary distributions includes `conf` subdir with my config file.

To summarize it, I have mainly these two questions:

- Is there (and should be?) any difference between local installation and installation from Git?
- Do you have any ideas why does my proprietary (`my_package`) repo not include `conf` dir although I was not able to reproduce this behavior? (I know this one is tricky since you do not have access to this repository.)

EDIT:

- there is no issue with uncommitted files (I checked this once more)
- install from Git includes `conf` dir with config file when I add `package_data` option to `setup.py` (but it does not explain the difference between local and through Git installation and it does not explain why it behaves differently for example project)
- I'm using Python 3.8.6
- my `pip` version is 20.3.3

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that some files are not commited to the repository, so you can find them locally but not remotely. Have you checked git status to see if you have any changes to commit to the repository? If everything shown to you is in the repository, may you have a .gitignore file that is hiding a file that you need for building the package? Ultimately, may you add your python version to the question? It may be relevant.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I've checked. I even went directly to gitlab to check whether `conf` is present there. When I add `package_data` option in `setup.py` then `conf` is correctly included even when installing through Git so there is definitely no issue with uncommitted files. My version of python is `3.8.6`.